# Birt Report Designer : Add label and dynamic text from dataSet

Tags: birt

I have a dataSet of person.

Is it possible to iterate and add label and dynamic text from dataSet in this format.

---

Name: John

Address : This is an exemple

Others label/text

---

Name: Alex

Address : This is an exemple

Others label/text

---

And so on.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. You should give more details.

Comment: I have in Java a list of person who contains also a list of company.
I created a dataset named person who contains Name, Address, Company name, etc.
In my layout I have only a title.
In a first time, I searched how to display the values in that format and after add the Company details who is in a nested list.
In the menu fetch menu, I put this 
if( !myIter.hasNext() )return false; 
val = myIter.next();
row["Name"]   = val.get(0);  
row["Address"]  = val.get(1);
return true;
It's work with a table but that's not the format I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list item instead of the table item.
Bind the list item to the data set (just as you would do with a table item).
Then, inside the list item's detail area,
create a grid item, say 2 cols x 3 rows.
You can that add your labels (static texts) like "Name:" to the cells in the left column and the data items to the right column of the grid.